# Parse.com include related objects in one to many relationship

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, nosql

Supposedly I have a database structure like this

```
Person ('name', 'age')
Belonging ('person', 'type')
```

with its relationship like this

```
Person -> Belongings (one to many)
```

and I want to query all person with their number of belongings included like this

```
Array[0] -> name, age, numberOfBelongings,
Array[1] -> name, age, numberOfBelongings,
etc
```

How do I do this? I tried to use **CloudCode** but, it turned out the fetching method is asynchronous, so I can't fetch the number of belongings to each person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly. If you need this count, you could create a field on the Person class (i.e. numberofbelongings) which you update in an afterSave cloud code hook on Belonging. Whenever a Belonging is saved, you also increment the numberofbelongings field on the Person object, and save that as well.

No extra queries, no extra network traffic from your device, and your always have the count available for any Person object.

Comment: Yea, I thought of that too. But it wouldn't be accurate if something happened when afterSave was executed, wouldn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by "happened"? You could run into concurrency-problems if a Person's belongings were changing very rapidly, but that does not seem likely. What did you have in mind?

Comment: yes, concurrency problem is what I have in mind. hahaha.. Ok, i'll try your suggestion. Thx